# How to replace the input channel shape from (224, 224, 3) to (224, 224, 1) in VGG16?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am using VGG16 for transfer learning. My images are grayscale. So, I need to change the input channel shape of Vgg16 from (224, 224, 3) to (224, 224, 1). I tried the following code and got error:

```
TypeError: build() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Can anyone help me where Am I doing it wrong?

```
vgg16_model= load_model('Fetched_VGG.h5')
vgg16_model.summary()

# transform the model to Sequential
model= Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[1:-1]:
    model.add(layer)

# Freezing the layers (Oppose weights to be updated)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.build(224,224,1)
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions'))
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `deeplearning4j` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't, even if you get rid of the input layer, this model has a graph that has already been compiled and your first **conv** layer expects an input with 3 channels. I don't think there is really an easy work around to make it accept 1 channel if there is any at all.

you need to repeat your data in third dimension and have the same grayscale image in all 3 bands instead of RGB, that works just fine.

if your image has the shape of : (224,224,1):

```
import numpy as np
gray_image_3band = np.repeat(gray_img, repeats = 3, axis = -1)
```

if your image has the shape of : (224,224)

```
gray_image_3band = np.repeat(gray_img[..., np.newaxis], repeats = 3, axis = -1)
```

you don't need to call the model.build() anymore this way, keep the input layer. but if you ever wanted to call it you need to pass the shape as a tuple like this:

```
model.build( (224, 224, 1) ) # this is correct, notice the parentheses
```

Comment: How to repeat the data in third dimension when the images are loaded in batches using ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory? For example, I loaded my data like:  test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(224, 224), classes=['Benign', 'Malignant'], batch_size=7, color_mode="grayscale"). In this case, the data are loaded into batches in gray scale.

When I investigate ''test_batches.image_shape'' The loaded image shape is (224,224,1).

Comment: iterate through your generator like this: for x_batch, y_batch in your_generator, and in the for loop apply the np.repeat to your images, if you don't want to confuse yourself in the process of indexing or using map function, just make empty place holders with np.zeros() for example , process images in batch one by one and put in your place holder. although this is very insufficient for training, you can change your images before training to appropriate size and save them in the their directory, then use generator on them.

Comment: I checked my images using matlab figure tool. For example, the channel is showing for a image as (0.422,0.422,0.422). So, the image is a 3 channel grayscale image. In that case, I don't need to change the image before training, Am i right? I just have to eliminate the parameter color_mode="grayscale" when batch loading the images, isn't is? I load the images batches in this approach and the input shape size is (224,224,3).

Comment: yes if it already has been extended to 3 dimensional images, you don't need to do any extra processing, just treat them as usual RGB images and feed them to model.